# How to plot graph for real time/dynamic values using Jfreechart in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, graph, jfreechart

I am trying to plot XY graph using jfreechart. I got some examples that plots graphs for fixed given values but I want to plot it for real time continuous values.

As I am beginner to this can any one guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding data after a chart has been created is very easy, just add a new series `dataset.addSeries(series)` or add an item to an existing series `series.add(item)`.  You can do this by making either the `dataset` or `series` a field rather then a local variable.  Create a new thread to add data.

There is an example in the [JFreeChart Samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and you can get the source code by buying the [developer guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)